# Remove line in dataframe with factor variable.

Tags: r

At this point my understanding on list, factor and data frame were juggle. I want to prepare data frame without the 1st line ~" ==== "

```
head(dats)
    V1      V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7   V8      V9     V10     V11          V12
1 ==== ======= === === === === === ==== ======= ======= ======= ============
2 WMAU 08/0000  26  24  89   0   0 10.0  FEW010  SCT140  BKN270             
3 WMAU 07/2300                                                              
4 WMAU 07/2200                                                              
5 WMAU 07/2100                                                              
6 WMAU 07/2000
```

result desire;

```
head(dats)
    V1      V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7   V8      V9     V10     V11          V12
1 WMAU 08/0000  26  24  89   0   0 10.0  FEW010  SCT140  BKN270           
2 WMAU 07/2300                                                              
3 WMAU 07/2200                                                              
4 WMAU 07/2100                                                              
5 WMAU 07/2000
```

I tried dats[,-1] & dats[-1], but it remove the entire dats$v1.

```
       V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7   V8      V9     V10     V11          V12
1 ======= === === === === === ==== ======= ======= ======= ============
2 08/0000  26  24  89   0   0 10.0  FEW010  SCT140  BKN270             
3 07/2300                                                              
4 07/2200                                                              
5 07/2100                                                              
6 07/2000
```

for information,

```
class(dats)
[1] "data.frame"
mode(dats)
[1] "list"
typeof(dats)
[1] "list"
str(dats)
'data.frame':   26 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ V1 : Factor w/ 2 levels "====","WMAU": 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V2 : Factor w/ 26 levels "=======","07/0000",..: 1 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 ...
```

Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: how about `dats[-1, ]`? to remove that row?

Comment: @din, thank you dear... I thought that little comma can be omit, not even try it. ^^'